Flutter TTS does not find 3rd party TTS engines
I have this Flutter Android App where I need to get TTS to speak a sentence. This works fine with the GoogleTTS but I would like a more natural voice like Acapela or Pico. But eventhough I set the TTS engine in the Android settings I only get Samsung and Google listed in the  flutterTts.getEngines
I have tried to do this also in Kotlin but that is the same.
Testing in multiple Samsung devices show the same behavior.
Here is a code snippet that reproduce the behaviour:
pubspec.yaml:   flutter_tts: ^4.0.2
      import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      class TestTTSPage extends StatefulWidget {
      
        const TestTTSPage({super.key});

        @override
        State<TestTTSPage> createState() => _TestTTSPageState();
      }
      //enum TtsState { playing, stopped, paused, continued }
      class _TestTTSPageState extends State<TestTTSPage> {

        late FlutterTts flutterTts;
        Future<dynamic> _getEngines() async => await                     flutterTts.getEngines;
        @override
        void initState() {
          super.initState();
          initTTS();
          }
          void initTTS() async
          {
            flutterTts = FlutterTts();
            var engines = await _getEngines();
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print(engines);
            }
          }
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          // TODO: implement build
          return const Text("");
        }

}

Just tested in an Android Emulator and this is also the same behavior. Only com.google.android.tts is showing eventhough I installed Acapela and this is set in the Android TTS settings. Heeeelp me Obiwans :-)

You should clarify how you are invoking on device TTS with code and stating which library/plug-in you may be using.

Sorry for the lack of code. I have edited:-)

So I've found: https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/issues/1862 which is only for one particular open-source TTS engine but may be relevant as you may want to list which TTS engines you are testing with (full name with link) and the OS versions of the devices you are testing on.
